# Python function force opens a new tab instead of opening the website in the current one

Tags: python, selenium

Currently i'm trying to do 2 functions, login into a forum and post a reply. The login is 1 function and posting the reply is another, for some reason when it's a function it opens a new tab instead of just opening the url in the current tab.

My code is right here:

```
    def __init__(self, login_url, time_for_bump):
        self.login_url = login_url
        self.time_for_bump = time_for_bump
        self.bump_phrase = "Bumpity bump"
        self.chrome = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/Kaihan/Desktop/Programming/Web Driver/Chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")

    def login(self, username, password):
        self.chrome.get(self.login_url)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.chrome.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector="#ctrl_pageLogin_login").send_keys(username)
        time.sleep(2)
        self.chrome.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector="#ctrl_pageLogin_password").send_keys(password)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.chrome.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector=".button").click()

    def bump_thread(self, thread):
        self.chrome.get(thread)
        time.sleep(2)
        self.chrome.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(2)
        self.chrome.find_element_by_xpath(xpath='//*[@id="QuickReply"]/div[1]/div/iframe').send_keys(self.bump_phrase)
        time.sleep(2)
        self.chrome.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector="input.button:nth-child(3)").click()
```

Comment: When you perform the steps manually, does it open in a new tab?

Comment: nop only when i use functions :(

Comment: Are you using the same class instance while calling the 2 functions? If you are using different instances then it's expected to open a new window, as browser initialization is part of your class init.